# how to set dns to azure kubenetes(acs) services?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-container-service

I am new to azure. I created an azure acs with kubenetes by using the following config(part of the whole file).

```
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: my-web
    spec:
      type: LoadBalancer
      ports:
      - port: 80
        targetPort: 3000
      selector:
        app: my-web
```

The service can be visited, but only via IP address. There is no secondary dns(like: xxx.azurewebsite.com) generated. Currently, I use A record points to the ip address. It works, but I am afraid the ip address will be changed, and I have to manually change the dns A record. Just asking if there is a way to generate some stable dns for acs services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Just asking if there is a way to generate some stable dns for acs
>   services?

We can via Azure portal to change the public IP address to static, in this way, restart the service will not change the IP.

But in Azure, if we **delete** the k8s service, the Public IP address will collected by Azure platform, and we will lose this IP address. For now, Azure does **not** support to keep the public IP address for k8s service.

Comment: Can generate some dns for acs load balance services?

Comment: @Ron For now, Azure does not support to set DNS for load balancer. we can via Azure portal to setup DNS for that public IP address.

Comment: in portal, do you mean custom DNS or azure public sencondary ones?

Comment: @Ron I mean we can set DNS in public IP address--> configuration--> DNS name label.

Comment: Got it, I tried it works. But the DNS is still bound to IP address, instead of k8s service. If pods gone, IP address re-assigned, the dns name label will disappear as well.

Comment: @Ron  For now, Azure does not support other way to setup DNS for Azure K8S, and if we delete the pods, IP address will re-assigned, that is a by design behavior(ACS). [AKS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-azure-container-service-aks-managed-kubernetes-and-azure-container-registry-geo-replication/) still in preview, after that completed, we can use that to create k8s cluster and that cluster support kube-dns. By the way, if my answer is helps, please don't forget to accept it as an answer so that other community members will be benefited, thanks:)